# How to make the DIV contents slide out and appear only when the user clicks on the DIV heading?

Tags: jquery, slidedown

If I have a DIV heading of `Contact Details` or `Address Details`, as in the following example:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/2CZFL/**](http://jsfiddle.net/2CZFL/)

how can I use jQuery to implement a feature whereby the contents of the div only slide out and appear to the user when the user clicks on the DIV heading.

Comment: there are lot of examples on the net , you can use jquery animate function and do lot of stuff , your fiddle example uses mototools , change it to jquery.

Answer (score 2):

See fiddle for how to make it open and close: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/wU8s2/

Comment: @Radu i had a brain freeze. thats very true. ill update the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple example

```
<script>
  jQuery(document.body).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.sneakycontent h3').click(function(){
      jQuery('.sneakycontent div').slideToggle();
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="sneakycontent">
  <h3>Click Me Newb!</h3>
  <div style="display:none;">Keep eating those stackoverflow weaties kiddies and you can be as cool as me!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Radu's fiddle is the best solution for the markup. Mine would require wrapping the elements in a parent, very heavy in comparison. jsfiddle.net/radu/yKvqX/1

Comment: my fiddle is the same thing... but doesnt change the OP's design

Answer (score 0):

Simple demo with using your fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/DR3x8/

[Make sure to add "display:none" to the content below the headers in order to hide them and only show when clicked.]